# Why hover selector doesn't work with clases?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have set the styles for  links (active, link, etc), but then I want to do a button with totally different styles so I tried something like this:

```css
.r-button { padding: 4px 52px; display: inline-block; text-align: center; font-size: 16px; text-decoration: none !important; color: black !important; border-radius: 12px; border:1px inset #282c37;}

.r-button:hover { cursor: selector; color:ivory;}
```

```html
<a class="r-button" onclick="document.getElementById('menu').style.display='block'">  Click button </a>
```

But then I realized that :hover doesn't work with clases. Why is that? What others chances do I have to do the same?

Comment: Don't (over)use `!important`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does, your `color: black !important;` is overriding the hover and that `selector` isn't a valid cursor. Try pointer on hover.

```
.r-button:hover { cursor: pointer; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to either REMOVE !important from your color in `.r-button` or add it to `.r-button:hover` 's color

```css
.r-button { padding: 4px 52px; display: inline-block; text-align: center; font-size: 16px; text-decoration: none !important; color: black !important; border-radius: 12px; border:1px inset #282c37;}

.r-button:hover { cursor: selector; color:ivory !important;}
```

```html
<a class="r-button" onclick="document.getElementById('menu').style.display='block'">  Click button </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `:hover` pseudo element was being overwritten with `!important`. Avoid using `!important` rules within your default class.

Bonus tip! Remove `cursor: pointer` for anchor tags, and simply have an empty `href="#"` attribute for better accessibility.

```css
.r-button {
  padding: 4px 52px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border: 1px inset #282c37;
}
.r-button:hover {
  background-color: #282c37;
  color: ivory;
}
```

```html
<a class="r-button" href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('menu').style.display='block'">Click button</a>
```